# Removing uncalled smali

Tags: android, compilers

Does anyone know of a smali re-compiler that will remove uncalled code without obfuscation? I just want to remove unused classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not smaili, but if you manage to decompile to java, use proguard. http://www.surrendercontrol.com/2016/03/using-proguard-to-deobfuscate-code.html